# JQuery Variable Wildcard or RegEx

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I have a condition that an action should only occur if a modal isn't currently open.  However, there could be multiple modals and the div's all have the same name followed by a number:

`stationListModal1`
`stationListModal2`
`stationListModal3`
etc

So essentially, I want my condition to evaluate whether any modal that starts with `stationListModal` is open without having to iterate through a count loop or anything like that.  Is this possible?  This what I have so far but not sure how to include `stationListModal` with any number that has the class.

```
if ($('#stationListModal').hasClass('in'))
...
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use attribute begins with selector

```
if ($("[id^=stationListModal]").hasClass("in")) {// do stuff}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let openCount = $('.stationListModal.in').length;

if (openCount) {}
else {}
```

Is it possible for you to add a class that all modals would share? If so, it becomes trivial

Comment: Makes the most sense to me.